# Apache Curator rebalancing client connections

Tags: apache, apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I'm new to curator, just curious about whether the curator framework internally handle the client connection rebalancing?  If not, I know the client will randomly choose a node to connect, is it necessary to do some client connections rebalancing?

Thanks a lot